# How to create user freindly routes for tagging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes, tagging

I have a model Image:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :size, :image, :tag_ids

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end
```

Then I have my Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :through => :taggings

end
```

My routes.rb is currently:

```
resources :images do
    get 'confirm_destroy', :on => :member
end
resources :tags
```

Now let's say I created a few tags "blue", "red" and "yellow" for the images. On some page I want to show a list of tags and then link them to e.g. www.example.com/yellow where all the images tagged as yellow shall be shown. The view (haml) for this tag list is currently:

```
- @tags.each do |tag|
  = link_to(tag.name, tag)
```

But it generates a link to www.example.com/tags/2 (with 2 being the tag_id).

How can I create the correct resources in order to link to www.example.com/yellow instead of www.example.com/tags/2. Will the view with "link_to" be the same in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to create a route to **www.example.com/yellow** because this doesn't reference a specific resource, and subsequently could create conflicts. Imagine if you had a tag called 'images', Rails wouldn't know if the url to **www.example.com/images** referred to a specific tag, or the images resource.

The best we can do is create a resource which uses the name as the identifier in the URL, such that **www.example.com/tags/yellow** would show the tag with 'yellow' as its name attribute.

To do this, you need to define the following **to_param** method in the model for Tag.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :through => :taggings

    def to_param
        name
    end
end
```

This will tell Rails to use the **name** attribute for routing instead of the default **id**. Your **link_to** won't need to be updated, however, your Tag controller will need to now find the Tag by name as opposed to ID, like so:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:id])
    end

    ...

end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is easy, but leads to the url www.example.com/tags/yellow. Can I get rid of the "/tags/" part of the url? Or even better substitute "/tags" with e.g. "/images" or any other name I chose? So, the ideal url would be www.example.com/images/yellow.

Comment: I just noticed that slight difference in your request. I've updated my answer to reflect why this can't be done. You also wouldn't be able to replace '/tags' with '/images' because that would again create a conflict within Rails and it wouldn't know which Resource to route to (Images or Tags).

Comment: On the other hand, you could use a completely different keyword (unused by other resources) by adding the following to your routes config: match '/different/:id' => 'tags#show'

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `to_param` method in your model or with `friendly_id` gem.
Ryan Bates has perfect screencast about this http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: Yes, good screencast and useful plugin. Anyhow, for now I go with to_params since it is sufficient for my purposes.